# How can i find the cssselector for the following error message

Tags: selenium, css-selectors

I am testing registration flow using selenium web driver. I have a field to enter email ID which shouldnt be the same as the user's emailId(user who is already registered). The code is mentioned below. I need to get the cssselector.

```
<em for="coworkeremail" class="error">Your co-worker's email must be different than yours</em>
```

Thanks
Java beginner

Comment: I'd try `".error"` or `"em.error"`

Comment: Did try both, getting Assertion error

Comment: Is the element you are looking for inside of a frame or iframe?

Comment: The text is inside a frame

Comment: You need to use `driver.SwitchTo().Frame("frameIdentifier");` where `frameIdentifier` is ideally the name or id of the frame.

Answer (score 1):

It's a little sketchy to match on that class, especially if there are more.  `error` is a very generic class, so i'd say match on the `for` attribute.

```
em.error[for='coworkeremail']
```

#### Edit

As you say in the comments, your element is in a frame.  Find the ID or Name of that frame, then execute,

```
driver.switchTo().frame("idOrName"); // assuming you are using Selenium 2 and Java
```

THEN find the element.

Answer (score 0):

Considering you only one element with `class = error`

`.error` is the CSS selector.

Comment: share your assertion code, also are you waiting for the error message to show up?

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"em.error"}
Command duration or timeout: 23 milliseconds

Comment: are you waiting for the error element to show up, before performing the assertion... ?

Comment: http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-and-implicit-waits-reference

Comment: yep. I am waiting for the error message before performing the assertion. thanks for the docs,ll try and check if that works. thanks @Amey